# mysql wrong explain join large table

Tags: mysql, join, explain

I have a 4Gb table and when I try to select row from it with left join on another table it creates very large temporary table on disc. 
My sql is:

```
 select * 
   from ads 
   left join theme 
     ON ads.theme_id = theme.id 
  ORDER BY ads.id DESC 
  limit 1
```

table `ads` has 4Gb of data but table `theme` is very small. When I try explain this query mysql doesn't shows me that temporary table will be created but it does. And when I use sql

```
SELECT * 
  from ads, 
       theme 
 where ads.theme_id = theme.id 
 ORDER BY ads.id DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

mysql runs very fast however this query has same explanation by mysql.

I use `innodb` engine  and I have only primary indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on `ads.theme_id`. Otherwise, it has to scan the entire `ads` table to check this column against `theme.id`.